# How to make projectile travel in a wave

Tags: java, libgdx, 2d

I have been trying to make my projectile travel in a wave but I can't figure out, how to do that. Right now my bullet is going towards the right side of the screen. Here is my code:

```
public class Projectile {

    protected Vector2 position;
    protected Vector2 velocity;

    public Projectile(float x, float y){

        position = new Vector2(x, y);
        velocity = new Vector2(50, 0);
    }

    public void update(float delta){

        position.add(velocity.cpy().scl(delta));
    }
}
```

I saw on the web about the function `Math.sin()` and `Math.toRadians()` that I can use but I have no idea how to use them or implement them.

I tried something along the line of `velocity.y += Math.sin(Math.toRadians(50))` before the `position.add` and my projectile is going downwards in a nice curve but I have no idea what am I doing at all! I want to be able to change the amplitude and frequency of the wave. Any help?

Comment: where is update() called?

Comment: @ZerO it's called in my GameWorld update, ArrayList<Projectile> projectiles = bird.getProjectiles();
  for (int i = 0; i < projectiles.size(); i++) {
   Projectile p = (Projectile) projectiles.get(i);
   if (p.isVisible() == true) {
    p.update(delta);
   } else {
    projectiles.remove(i);
   }
  }

Comment: delta is elapsed time?

Comment: @ZerO Oh no, the delta is the number of seconds that has passed since the last time that the render method was called. I have a render method calling the GameWorld update. The render method is the game loop.

Comment: yeah that is what i meant :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay solution should be simple:

What you are doing atm is: You have a 2D position. now you add a 2D vector to it, which represents your speed `(50, 0) * delta` where delta is the elapsed time.
now think about how you could represent your x- and y-direction changes with a sine-function. this is not hard at all, it is just math.

Comment: oh dear I am kinda bad in trigonometry/math stuff. I will go and figure it out how to do it. Thanks! :-)

Comment: your welcome! if your answer was solved by this, do not forget to mark this as an accepted answer, so your question is solved.

ZerO